# DataBinding for DataGrid not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I am using a `ObservableCollection` defined in my MainWindow classs of a simple WPF application. For some reason the list updates (I can see this when debugging), however the UI does not update.

Now, if I create a `Timer` and loop it, I can update the `DataGrid` by setting the `ItemSource`. This works, but causes a horrible flickering in my DataGrid.

```
public ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> calculatedData { get; set; }
```

Further down into my code, I use this line to actually update or add data to the list.

```
calculatedData = await CalculateData();
```

The `CalculateData` function is defined as follows:

```
private Task<ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>> CalculateData()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> cdList = new ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>();
        // Do a lot of stuff
        return cdList;
    });
}
```

For my `xaml` I have a simple DataGrid as shown below:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding calculatedData}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

**Question:** Why is the DataGrid not being upadted? Will this fix my flickering issue since i'm not re-binding?

-

**UPDATE**

I even changed my main declaration to the following (since Iv'e seen it done this way), but I have still not gotten it to work.

```
private ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> calculatedData = new ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>();
public ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> CalculatedData
{
    get { return calculatedData; }
    set
    {
        calculatedData = value;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CalculatedData}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

Comment: what is happening in  "dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan good question! I'm removing a certain column and just renaming other column  headers. So, nothing unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply do:

```
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calculatedData = await CalculateData();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = calculatedData;
    }
```

it will work. I guess your XAML binding is probably not working because `DataContext` is not defined.

**EDIT: Here's full code,**

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> calculatedData { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        calculatedData = await CalculateData();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = calculatedData;
    }

    private Task<ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>> CalculateData()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> cdList = new ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>();

            // Do a lot of stuff
            cdList.Add(new CalculatedData { Data1 = 1, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 3 });
            cdList.Add(new CalculatedData { Data1 = 1, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 3 });
            cdList.Add(new CalculatedData { Data1 = 1, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 3 });
            cdList.Add(new CalculatedData { Data1 = 1, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 3 });
            cdList.Add(new CalculatedData { Data1 = 1, Data2 = 2, Data3 = 3 });

            return cdList;
        });
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Margin="0" />
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

EDIT 2: added a button and moved code around a little so you can test.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> calculatedData { get; set; }
    int i;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //initialize your binding collection
        calculatedData = new ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>();
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        i = 1;
        //create initial data and bind to data grid
        calculatedData = await CalculateData();
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = calculatedData;
    }

    private Task<ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>> CalculateData()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> cdList = new ObservableCollection<CalculatedData>();

            // Do a lot of stuff
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                cdList.Add(new CalculatedData { Data1 = i, Data2 = i + 1, Data3 = i + 2 });
                i++;
            }

            return cdList;
        });
    }
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //place new data in a temporary collection
        ObservableCollection<CalculatedData> newData = await CalculateData();

        //add new data to the collection bound to the data grid
        //preferably, don't just replace it
        //any business logic you may need for adding, 
        //deleting, filtering data, etc goes here 
        foreach (CalculatedData cd in newData)
            calculatedData.Add(cd);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my `MainWindow` constructor, I added `DataContext = this;` and I get the column headers, but still no data??

Comment: You don't even need DataContext. I'll edit my answer with full code.

Comment: I do the same thing you are doing, but in a timer tick function. However, this causes horrible flickering with my DataGrid. That's what im trying to avoid. (as well as setting the itemsource every tick).

Comment: The Timer is probably causing flickering. But you don't need the timer either. Take a look at full code I posted.

Comment: That works! But why are my XAML bindings not working? And do i have to implement `ObservableCollection` rather then a simple List?

Comment: You can do it through XAML binding as well, but it is a complete different scenario. Because DataGrid binds directly using ItemsSource, it is just easier to do it through code-behind. Yes, ObservableCollection<> is a must in this case just because List<> does not implement the required interfaces that enables binding.

Comment: ah ok. I just noticed that the UI still does not change when the list changes, even though im using an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84950/discussion-between-fear-code-and-jstreet).

Comment: Added a button for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the items source each time try adding items from result of CalculateData();

```
var data = await CalculateData();
foreach(var d in data)
   calculatedData.Add(d);
```

also not sure if you are initialized your CalculatedData property init in constructor.

```
CalculatedData = new ObservableCollection<yourType>();
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: This still does not work for me. The items are in my List, but the UI never updates and my datagrid is just blank (not even the header columns are showing).